# How I can run SSRS report from Epicor 10 Dashboard?

Tags: ssrs-2008, epicorerp

I have created some BAQ reports and new styles for different Forms for SSRS. But I can not find, How to create and use SSRS reports from Dashboard? Is it possible?

Comment: Can an epicor dashboard display a web page? You can run a SSRS report by using the correct URL

Answer (score 0):

You can add a customization layer while in Developer mode to any dashboard so long as it is of program type "Dashboard-Assembly". Essentially you have to build and deploy it first and not just use it as "Dashboard-Runtime".

The customization of it is similar to most other UI forms, but I have noticed it is a bit more limited it scope.  I have never done exactly what you are doing, but I imagine that if you can trace out what you want to do you should be able to replicate it in your customization.

Good luck.